# django duplicates the name of model for migration table

Tags: python, django, migration

when i migrate my django 2 models it makes tables without any problem but the name of table is like this :‌nameofmodel_nameofmodel !!! so for example booking_booking !!!
here is my code :

```
    from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Booking(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True )
    operator_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True )
    computed_net_price = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True )
    final_net_price = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True )
    payable_price = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True )
    booking_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True )
    guest_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True )
    guest_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True )
    guest_cellphone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True )
    from_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=50, null=True )
    to_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=50, null=True )
    is_removed = models.IntegerField(null=True )
```

and here is my serializer :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Booking
class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Booking
         fields =(
             'user_id',
             'computed_net_price',
             'final_net_price',
             'payable_price',
             'booking_status',
             'booking_status',
             'guest_name',
             'guest_last_name',
             'guest_cellphone',
             'guest_cellphone',
             'guest_cellphone',
             'operator_id',
             'is_removed',
         )
```

so what is the standard naming of django and what if i want to have it in a different way and i am doing correctly or not

Comment: It is formed like "yourappname_yourtablename". Table name is saved in django in this way. I think your model is standard.
https://djangobook.com/mdj2-models/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make like that:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    # first_field = ....
    # second_field = ....

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table_name'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#meta-options